# the stability group the action of Fuchsian group on the extended complex plane is cyclic?

Tags: dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\hat{\mathbb C}:=\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\} $ be the extended complex plane. I found the following proposition 2.2. from Iwaniec's Spectral methods in automorphic forms but I can't find a proof of it.

> Any stability group
>   $\Gamma_z:=\{\gamma\in \Gamma:\gamma.z=z\}$
>    the action of Fuchsian group on the extended complex plane is cyclic.

Can anyone show me a proof or a reference to a proof?

Source:
[image]

Comment: "Fuchsian" or "fusian"?

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry my bad...

Answer (score 1):

My go-to reference for such questions is

A.F.Beardon, "Geometry of Discrete Groups", Springer Verlag, 1983.

See Theorem 8.2.1 in his book: If $\Gamma$ is a Fuchsian group then the $\Gamma$-stabilizer $\Gamma_z$ of any point $z\in \hat{\mathbb C}$ is cyclic.

The key to the proof is that all (nontrivial) elements of $\Gamma_z$  are of the same type (either all are elliptic: when $z$ is not on the invariant circle) or all are parabolic or all are hyperbolic (when $z$ is a limit point).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in your other questions.

- The action of $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ on the upper half-plane is transitive, $z=g.i$,  $Stab(z) = g Stab(i) g^{-1}$
- $\frac{ai+b}{ci+d} = i $ implies $ci+d = -a+ib$ thus $Stab(i) = SO_2(\Bbb{R})$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R/Z}$.
- If $G$ is discrete in $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ then $G \cap SO_2(\Bbb{R})$ is discrete in $SO_2(\Bbb{R})$, an infinite subgroup of $\Bbb{R/Z}$ has some elements arbitrary close $0$ thus such a subgroup is dense, thus discete subgroup of $\Bbb{R/Z}$ must be finite and cyclic.
- When you add $\infty$ you get a new kind of stabilizer $Stab(\infty) = \pmatrix{a &b\\ 0 & a^{-1}}$, you need to make clear the topology you put on it

Comment: What you wrote is not quite right: The point stabilizers are either cyclic elliptic or cyclic parabolic or cyclic hyperbolic (the case that you missed). Also, the action of a Fuchsian group on the complex projective line is far from being  transitive.

Comment: you meant $z \mapsto az+b$ sends $\infty$ of upper half-plane to itself. $g$ is not in the fushian group

Comment: If you are not considering the point stabilizer in a Fuchsian group (but rather in the entire $PSL(2,R)$) then you are answering a wrong question. The examples you gave (item 4) cannot be in a Fuchsian group. (Fuchsian group, by definition, is a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,R)$, your example is not.)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, please make things simple and clear. I don't even know what topology and group you and the OP wants to consider. $\{z \mapsto 2^k z+2^k n\}$ acts discretely on  $\Bbb{H}$ but if we add $\infty$ plus a chart it won't be discrete, in contrary to $z \mapsto z+n$.

Comment: You might take a look at the wikipedia entry on Fuchsian groups, in order to understand the topology and group that are relevant to this question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group. In the first sentence of that entry, you might also follow the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_group.

Comment: Perhaps the key point is that a discrete group of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ does indeed act discretely on $\mathbb H$, but its action on the whole of $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ need not be a discrete action.

Comment: @reuns: The topology is the standard topology on the extended complex plane and on $SL(2,R)$ and the quotient topology on $PSL(2,R)$. The set of affine transformations $\{z\mapsto 2^k z+ 2^k n: k\in {\mathbb Z}, n\in {\mathbb Z}\}$ does not form a group (only a semigroup); the group this set generates does not act properly discontinuously on the upper half-plane.